# How do you get this weeks Tuesday in JS? Without any libraries

Tags: javascript

I've seen examples on SO of getting the next Monday but I need to get this week's current Tuesday. Is anyone out there please able to get this? I don't want to use any libraries.

I.e. Since it's Wednesday 24/04/2019, I'd like to get the date 23/04/2019 in a variable.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((7 - d.getDay()) % 7 + 2) % 7);
console.log(d)
```

This is the code I tried to get the next Tueday, I just need to get the current weeks Tuesday. If it's Monday then it'd get the next day's date, if it's Friday it'd get the previous Tuesday, any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you have permission to use [Deborah Kurata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647604/deborahk)'s face as your profile pic?

Comment: @Igor, huge inspiration of mine. Any idea on the answer to this question?

Comment: @adiga The answer there only works if you consider the week to start on the day you're looking for. It doesn't generalize to other days of the week.

Comment: KISS: `d.getDate() - d.getDay() + 2`. The `% 7` don't harm, but adding `7` does.

Comment: `huge inspiration of mine` <= If you admire her it's all the more reason to ask/check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the current day of week from 2, and add that to the current date.

If the current day is Wednesday (`3`), `2-3 = -1`, and when you add `-1` to the current date you get the previous date, which is Tuesday.

If the current day is Monday (`1`), `2-1 = 1`, and when you add `1` to the current date you get the next date, which is Tuesday.

```js
var d = new Date();
dayDiff = 2 - d.getDay();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + dayDiff);
console.log(d);
```

This assumes you consider Sunday the start of the current week. If the week starts on Monday instead of Sunday, you'll have to treat Sunday specially.

Comment: Yeah I do assume the week starts on Sunday, chur. Dunno why this was flagged, as the duplicated answer didn't answer my question.

Comment: Because they didn't realize the important differences.

Comment: @MoneyMurch please don't accept the duplicate if doesn't answer your question :)

Comment: @adiga What are you talking about? You don't get to accept duplicates. All you can do is ask for your question to be reopened. I already reopened the question because the duplicate wasn't appropriate.

Comment: @Barmar no, the question is rightfully reopened. I was replying to OP. They accepted the duplicate since it was closed by the Community user